# Get mySQL rows in minute-by-minute time range over multiple hours

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I could try doing this by PHP but I think it could be done simply in mySQL. I have rows in mySQL with a date time over multiple hours. I want to return the counts for each minute interval during those multiple hours.

`GROUP BY MINUTE(date)`

gives me 60 rows, but it doesn't give me the counts for 01:00:00 - 01:01:00 differently from 02:00:00 and 02:00:01.

How can this be done?

Comment: What about the date itself? do you want to group Sundays minutes together with Mondays minutes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

MySQL minute function is literally taking the minute number and grouping by that. Try grouping by hour then minute:

```
GROUP BY HOUR(date), MINUTE(date)
```

Answer (score 25):

New answer for old question!

To group by minute, you can simply:

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp(`date`) - unix_timestamp(`date`)%60) groupTime, count(*) 
FROM yourTable
# WHERE clause
GROUP BY groupTime
```

With this solution, you will never mixed datetimes of a minute with datetimes of the same minute of another hour, day, ...

Plus, It's an evolutive solution because, by changing "60" to another number, you can group by a couple of minutes (120), by a day (86400), ...

Comment: One major side-benefit to this solution is that if you store timestamps rather than dates then you can remove the unix_timestamp() parts and still group by minutes for example - amazing!

Comment: really really awesome!

Comment: Best answer for me...

Answer (score 20):

Just use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%H:%i')
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for me: ``SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`execute_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), COUNT(*)
FROM
    automations
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`execute_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
ORDER BY count(*) DESC``

Answer (score 8):

Since MySql stores dates/times as a full number, dividing the number by 100 will give you the minute:

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(`data` / 100)
```

Grouping by a number is more efficient then grouping by text.

If you want to group by minute regardless of the date:

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(`data` / 100) % 10000
```

Comment: very halpfull answer Thanks !:) 

1000  10 minute
10000 1 hr
20000 2 hr

Answer (score 2):

For those who have searched the same result but using UNIX time (number of seconds from 1970-01-01) you can use:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix_time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as minute,
    COUNT(id) as number_total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY minute
```

For more date functions > https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dates to stay the same and just group by discarding the seconds, and your date field is date_time format (not VARCHAR). (Note: leave out -%i if you want to group by hour )

```
SELECT
   date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as minute_format
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY 1;
```